# How to make the rest of the mask transparent in Premier Pro CS6?

Tags: video, premiere

I'm trying to highlight a part of my video. Since I'm totally new to video editing on Premier Pro - I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing that, but I'm using masks.

I have a title sitting in `video 2` row, in it a have a rectangular mask (100% opacity)

[image: title]

I then apply a `Track Matte Key` effect on the video I'm trying to highlight, and get the following result:

[image]

This seems like a step in the right direction, but I can't find the place to change the settings of the mask to enable transparency. The intended result is to have dimmed out frame, with only the masked area fully shown.

This is the `Effect Controls` screen for my video:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now that I was able to reproduce your technique thus far, I can fill in the missing pieces.  Your use of the Track Matte Key produces a layer that is transparent everywhere other than where the mask is present.  You need to layer it overtop of the video that you want behind it and you need to apply the dimming effect to the background layer.

In your example, Move video 2 to Video 3 and copy Video 1 to Video 2.  Leave the track matte key on Video 2 and remove it from Video 1.  This will layer the highlighted area (Video 2) over the full video (Video 1).  You can then either reduce the opacity or apply a brightness reduction to Video 1 to make it appear more subdued and get the look you are going for.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer @AJ, what still puzzles me - how/where do I make the mask grey? Screenshots would be so much appreciated! :)

Comment: @MorganWilde - I can post screenshots later, but at the moment my Premiere system isn't accessible to me.  If you are using solids, you should be able to change the color of it when making the solid at least.  I believe there is a way to change it after as well, but I don't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: I really hope to hear from you soon @Aj, since I've yet to solve my issue :/

Comment: @MorganWilde - I'll be home in about 3 hours.  I'll take a look first thing when I get home and post after that.

Comment: @MorganWilde - ok, you were going about it a slightly different way from how I normally would, but your way should work fine.  I have updated my answer to reflect the missing steps in your approach.  Let me know if you still need screen shots.

Comment: that definitely did the trick, and I now understand premier pro much better now :) thanks!

Comment: @MorganWilde - no problem.  Sorry I couldn't tell you off the top of my head.  I usually do this kind of a thing in After Effects which is more purpose built for compositing type effects like this.  Back in the day, it was the only way, but they've added more and more features to Premiere over the years. (I've been using Premiere since version 5, not CS5 mind you, 5 from before there was a CS.)

Comment: well it's just awesome that this community has people like you :) I was a bit unsure before posting if anyone qualified could answer...